# Set folder permission for a IIS application pool with C# Console application

Tags: c#

I want, programatically, set folder permissions for an user (which is IIS application pool) like:

```
string websiteDict = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo( websiteDict );
DirectorySecurity ds = di.GetAccessControl();

ds.SetAccessRule( new FileSystemAccessRule( @"IIS AppPool\myAppPool", FileSystemRights.FullControl,
AccessControlType.Allow ) );

di.SetAccessControl( ds );
```

The problem that user (myAppPool) added by rule above, has no rights, nothing is ticked in **Allow** column (see **Security** tab from **Properties** dialog) even I set full access control.

I run executable program as administrator, but same thing.

Why ?

Comment: If you try and do this manually does your machine accept a group/username of "IIS AppPool\myAppPool"?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - I managed to set permissions for IIS APPPOOL successfully (in my case - Modify, which I would highly recommend instead of Full Control, unless your app pool really needs to change ownership of the files inside these folders). However, when I checked it in the file system, I noticed that no checkboxes are shown for the app pool.

After taking a closer look, I noticed that there is a checkbox for Special Permissions (you have to scroll down one item in the list of permissions). Then I clicked the Advanced button, opened the permissions for my apppool and realized that it does have Modify permission, but no inheritance of rights is configured. If I set the "Applies To" field to "This folder, subfolders and files" manually, all the expected checkboxes appear where they should.

To set "Applies To" to "This folder, subfolder and files", you have to add three ACL rules, not one, like this:

```cs
var pathToGrantRights = fs.Path.Combine(Folder, "App_Data");
fs.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToGrantRights);
var acl = fs.Directory.GetAccessControl(pathToGrantRights);

string acc = $"IIS APPPOOL\\{webapp.ApplicationPoolName}";
acl.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(acc, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow));
acl.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(acc, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
acl.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(acc, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
fs.Directory.SetAccessControl(pathToGrantRights, acl);
```

When you add the inheritance for folders and files in addition to the object itself, it starts working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I checked on my server and the pools didnt show directly as groups I could use under windows to assign.

In your case "IIS AppPool\myAppPool" may not be available to windows as a security group. If not, it cant then apply it to permissions.

Comment: I tried on production, user exists but still no checkbox for allow is done...What's wrong ?

Comment: I tried manually, works. If I do through C#, not working, even start console as administrator

Comment: OK, so thats a good start - let me dig up some code, Im on a phone call most of the day about something entirely unrelated and may not get to do much.. but.. I'll see what I can dig up. I do remember something ...